# Woocommerce variable product load time on many variations

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a site where several products have more than 2000 (two thousand) variations. It's a bit troublesome regarding performance.

Specifically, page load time was terrible, because I disabled AJAX price loading (I needed all variation data available at the same time, for displaying intermediate prices on variations before you change options), so no matter the amount of variations, the data would always echo into the `.variation_form`'s `data-product-variations` attribute.

Now, I've decided to disable that as well, and on page load get the data asynchronously and initiate the form only after I have the data. It works.

My problem begins here, because the product page still loads the same length of time now as it did when I was fetching and echoing all available variations. My theory was that it would now display as fast as a simple product, then wait for AJAX to get and initiate the form.

What is the reason for the long load time? The complexity of the product, or isthere still something processing all the variations somewhere? I'd love to stop it if possible. Any hints on where to look or what to measure would be appreciated.

I used microtime() to get this far and find out that get_available_variations() would take 5-10 seconds to get all the data, that's why I thought doing that async would be the key change needed.

Answer (score 0):

My question is pointless, I now see. The problem was in the Woocommerce sidebar, because I was printing the prices differently on products in the sidebar, I forgot at some point I used the get_available_variations function.

I'm displaying the prices in the sidebar differently now and the variable product loads as quickly as a simple product.